# How can I use a nix configuration when not using Nixos?

Tags: nix, nixos

So I've installed Nix on Arch linux and I'm able to run `nix-env -i example`, however how can I define a Nix configuration?

As I don't have any `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file present.

Is this possible?

---

My goal here is to be able to define a configuration which I could then use something like `nixos-rebuild switch` to install and provision all the software.

Comment: Relevant: [How to configure a Nix environment, outside of NixOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369234/how-to-configure-a-nix-environment-outside-of-nixos) and the [`rycee/home-manager`](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager) tool.

Answer (score 9):

I use NixOS, but I use `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` to describe my *system*; I keep it fairly minimal and prefer not to install "user" software by editing configuration.nix.

So what I do instead is use my `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` (which I believe you also have an equivalent of even in a non-NixOS nix install? I've never actually used nix separately).

The basic structure I use is this:

```
{
  packageOverrides = nixpkgs: with nixpkgs; rec {
    mine = with pkgs; buildEnv {
      name = "mine";
      paths = [
        # your packages here
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

`buildEnv` is a convenience function from nix that makes an "environment" package out of a bunch of others; installing the package `mine` depends on (and so installs) all of the things listed in `paths`, and also makes sure they get included in `PATH` and things like that.

Then I just use `nix-env -riA nixos.mine` to deploy changes I've made to my environment description (or to rebuild my environment following channel updates). The `-r` tells it to remove everything else other than `mine` from the new generation of my profile, which means I can (ab?)use `nix-env -i some-package` as a way of "temporarily" installing `some-package`, and if I don't decide I like it enough to actually record it in my config.nix it'll just get removed anyway next time I deploy.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly create your own configuration. For example, you can do something like this:

```
let
    pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in
    {    
        packages = [
            pkgs.vim
            pkgs.gimp
        ];
    }
```

That would produce a set containing an attribute called `packages`, containing a list of Nix packages. But, you'd need to develop a tool to build environments from this, which is part of what `nix-env` does. For example, the tool can use `nix-env` to determine what is already installed, compare that to the selected packages in the configuration, and then install/uninstall packages accordingly.

You don't have a `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` because that's NixOS-specific. So while you can do as you asked, you'd have to roll your own solution.

Comment: I suppose if I didn't use any services I could mount a Nixos filesystem and chroot into that?

I might try to do this in a Docker container otherwise.

Comment: Probably... but that's getting awful complicated. If all you want to do is install packages in-mass, you can feed them all into `nix-env` at once, and then use it's upgrade feature to upgrade all the packages at once. That way, a rollback would undo upgrading the entire set of packages, like on NixOS. If Arch Linux is set up to use systemd, then you can "boot" it within a systemd-nspawn container from NixOS (or any other systemd-equipped OS).